# Error: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I am trying to load data-table with ajax call to controller.
while calling ajax ..it will execute and return data but in console it give me error like "Cannot read property 'style' of undefined".

i am trying following code

```js
        var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

        //$(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
        editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
            ajax: "PRC/PRCGenerate",
            table: "#example",
            fields: [{
                label: "PQTY",
                name: "PQTY"
            }, {
                label: "PRCReadyDT",
                name: "PRCReadyDT"
            }, {
                label: "REMARKS:",
                name: "REMARKS"
            }
            ]
        });

        // Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell
        $('#example').on('click', 'tbody td.editable', function (e) {
            editor.inline(this);
        });

        $('#example').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            ajax: 'PRC/PRCGenerate',
            columns: [
                {
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: '',
                    className: 'select-checkbox',
                    orderable: false
                },
                { data: 'OANO' },
                { data: 'ID' },
                { data: 'PONO' },
                { data: 'POLI' },
                { data: 'MOULDCODE' },
                { data: 'DESCRIPTION' },
                { data: 'Drg' },
                { data: 'Rev' },
                { data: 'METALCODE' },
                { data: 'METALNAME' },
                { data: 'WEIGHT' },
                { data: 'QTY' },
                { data: 'PQTY', className: 'editable' },
                { data: 'Machining' },
                { data: 'PRC' },
                { data: 'DELIVERYDT' },
                { data: 'PRCReadyDT', className: 'editable' },
                { data: 'PRCNO' },
                { data: 'REMARKS', className: 'editable' }
                //render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '$'),
            ],
            select: {
                style: 'os',
                selector: 'td:first-child'
            },
            buttons: [
                { extend: 'create', editor: editor },
                { extend: 'edit', editor: editor },
                { extend: 'remove', editor: editor }
            ]
        });
        //});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.7/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
@model IEnumerable<RedICMVC.Models.sp_PRC_Record_Result>
<div class="card">
    <table id="example" class="table display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.OANO)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PONO)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.POLI)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MOULDCODE)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DESCRIPTION)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Drg)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Rev)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.METALCODE)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.METALNAME)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.WEIGHT)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.QTY)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PQTY)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Machining)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PRC)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DELIVERYDT)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PRCReadyDT)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PRCNO)
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.REMARKS)
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

And The output shown like this with error
[image: Output With Error]
How can i solve this.?
please Help Me..
thanks in advance.:-)

Comment: maybe your `jquery` is running before the successful ajax call. so they are not getting the `td`. you can try by using `setTimeout` function or run the function after the ajax call.

Comment: where i have to write setTimeout.?

Comment: maybe it is happening because you don,t have any `td` tags

Comment: i refer this link for generate table

https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/columns.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to query the td elements before they have been created by dataTables. You can add any code that need to be run after the table has generated to the initComplete callback like so:

```
$('#example').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        ajax: 'PRC/PRCGenerate',
        columns: [
            {
                data: null,
                defaultContent: '',
                className: 'select-checkbox',
                orderable: false
            },
            { data: 'OANO' },
            { data: 'ID' },
            { data: 'PONO' },
            { data: 'POLI' },
            { data: 'MOULDCODE' },
            { data: 'DESCRIPTION' },
            { data: 'Drg' },
            { data: 'Rev' },
            { data: 'METALCODE' },
            { data: 'METALNAME' },
            { data: 'WEIGHT' },
            { data: 'QTY' },
            { data: 'PQTY', className: 'editable' },
            { data: 'Machining' },
            { data: 'PRC' },
            { data: 'DELIVERYDT' },
            { data: 'PRCReadyDT', className: 'editable' },
            { data: 'PRCNO' },
            { data: 'REMARKS', className: 'editable' }
            //render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '$'),
        ],
        select: {
            style: 'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        buttons: [
            { extend: 'create', editor: editor },
            { extend: 'edit', editor: editor },
            { extend: 'remove', editor: editor }
        ],
        initComplete: function () {
            editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor({
                ajax: "PRC/PRCGenerate",
                table: "#example",
                fields: [{
                    label: "PQTY",
                    name: "PQTY"
                }, {
                    label: "PRCReadyDT",
                    name: "PRCReadyDT"
                }, {
                    label: "REMARKS:",
                    name: "REMARKS"
                }
                ]
            });

            // Activate an inline edit on click of a table cell
            $('#example').on('click', 'tbody td.editable', function (e) {
                editor.inline(this);
            });
        }
    });
```

There are a couple of other events you can use beside initComplete that might work for your use-case, they can be found [here](https://datatables.net/reference/event/). You may also want to look into using the draw event instead depending on how large your table will be and whether or not you are using paging.

Comment: i replace my code with your code. my error is solve but new error accrue.

"Cannot read property 'i18n' of null". what is the problem for this.?

Comment: Try the discussion below maybe?    https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/25165/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-i18n-of-null